# Excel to return a list values in the dropdown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get values to dropdown list from current row and rows above.I used excel's VLOOKUP function.As shown in screenshot given an Account Type(Column A) I want to get its account name for the current and rows above. In order words, when A4 value is ASSET I want to get Account Names(house,furniture,Shop) for dropdown list E4,or when I select LIABILITY I want to get Account Name for such etc.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you describe in your question is called dependent Data Validation. You set up range names with the values and the range names are the same as the values in column A. Then use an Indirect(A1) as the data source for the data validation in cell E1.

A full tutorial with walk-through has been written up by Debra Dalgleish at Contextures.com [www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)